# You think you're right but you're actually wrong

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word for when someone is wrong, and they know they're wrong, but they insist that they are right?

EDIT:
If someone does something and you know they did it, and they know they did it, but they keep telling everyone they didn't do it, and they go out of their way to try and convince others that they didn't do it.

(Example:  Someone steals your dog.  You know it's your dog.  Your dog knows he's your dog.  But the thief goes around saying its their dog and produces false receipts or photos (of other dogs), etc.)

Comment: Is this argument still going on as you type? :-)

Comment: This question is hard for me to follow. They know they're wrong but they think they're right?

Comment: Which is it, do they think they're right or wrong?

Comment: The technical term is confused.

Comment: LOL Sorry folks.  No argument going on.  Trying to come up with a good adj to describe someone who does something, knows they did it, but then tries to tell other people they didn't do it.  Having a hard time think of the right word here, so describing it is kind of hard.

Comment: @Jeremy: It's the dog that clarifies things. You cannot be mistaken if you (and your dog) both know that it's *your* dog. So even if the liar hopes to convince other people that the dog he has is not yours, both he and you know that he can *never* convince you. You and the liar both know that he's lying, but he still hopes to persuade other people to believe his lie. You of course, will be absolutely spitting blood - but sometimes it just happens that way.

Comment: I believe the word is "politician."

Comment: There is a good four letter word for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The person is definitely a [**liar**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/liar).  If they really are believing the lie, then they might even be [**delusional**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/delusional).

Comment: Thank you!  Delusions of Grandeur is actually what I was thinking of but couldn't remember.

Comment: "Deluded" is a way to back off the clinical label of "delusional", too.

Comment: @Rodeo: A _delusion of grandeur_ is a false impression of one's importance; more like like lying to yourself than to another.

Comment: *Delusions of grandeur* is definitely not an answer to the question as it's currently stated. It's not even this answer. I think you think you're right, but you're actually wrong.

Answer (score 8):

As @jimreed says, such a person is a **liar**. This basically covers all contexts where someone says something that *they know is untrue*. But OP is specifically looking for a way to describe a liar who is aware that at least *some other people know for certain that what he says untrue*.

The most common terms for the specific context are **brazen** and **barefaced liar**, both of which occur [about equally](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=barefaced%20liar,brazen%20liar,&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). Both these adjectives are also commonly applied to the lie itself, but for some reason [*barefaced lie* is more common than *brazen lie*](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=barefaced%20lie,brazen%20lie&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

A common coarse slang term that comes to mind is [bullshitter](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bullshitter). I'm not saying Urban Dictionary is always a reliable authority, but I can't fault the example in definition 7 there - *Someone who will claim he drank 2 litres of vodka and was not drunk*.

Comment: +1 with caveat: personally I feel that BRAZEN is more fitting to what the OP is looking for (as in "stupidly bold"). To me, BAREFACED denotes that most people don't believe the lie. The lie is so obvious, it is "written on the liar's bare face".

Comment: @Martin S. Stoller: I didn't say so in the answer, but I personally would probably normally call someone a *brazen liar*, and accuse them of coming out with a *barefaced lie*. If you'd habitually make that subtle distinction between them, you're a more precise speaker than me. I'd just use my two pairings practically every time because they're what rolls off my tongue. Which makes sense with *barefaced lie*, because I'd hear that more. I think I say *brazen liar* because I also say *brazen hussy*, so I'm more used to applying *brazen* to people, not to lies.

Comment: ...plus whilst I like the idea of *written on the liar's bare face, I don't think the *guilt written all over your face* interpretation directly relates to [the origin of barefaced](http://www.word-detective.com/092906A.html#barefaced), which is simply *beardless, undisguised*.

Comment: Have you noticed how variants on *barefaced lie/liar* have been cropping up of late?  You now see *boldfaced* and even *baldfaced* showing up a good deal, mostly over the last 30–40 years. Ngrams [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bare+-+faced+liar%2Cbald+-+faced+liar%2Cbold+-+faced+liar&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=2) and [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bare+-+faced+lie%2Cbald+-+faced+lie%2Cbold+-+faced+lie&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=2). Plus rerun as a single unhyphenated word for even more of a neologistic shift.

Comment: @tchrist: Strange: The absolute numbers are unexpectedly high. Still [swamped by the "correct" version](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=barefaced+lie%2Cboldfaced+lie%2Cbaldfaced+lie&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), but definitely on the rise. You can see why though - take out the word *"faced"*, and *"a lie"* is [more likely to be *bold* or *bald* than *bare*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+bold+lie%2Ca+bald+lie%2Ca+bare+lie&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I’ve no data, but my hunch is that the original version is less commonly heard than these new  alternatives amongst contemporary American speakers, particularly youth. Data on actual speech is hard to come by, but [Googlefight](http://googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=bold-faced+lie&word2=bare-faced+lie) has *bare-faced lie* as only twice as frequent as *bald-faced lie*.  Odd; faces aren’t normally called bald, only pates.

Answer (score 3):

'Pig-headed' is the word I'd use.

Comment: pigheadedness, yes.

Answer (score 3):

If he knows is wrong, but is trying to prevent others from detecting the wrongness, he is being **deceitful** .

You may also call him a **fabricator**, a **liar**, or a **whitewasher** — although that less [connotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitewash_%28censorship%29) lying about knowing the truth than of glossing over a transgression.

The act, by the way, is called [**scapegoating**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scapegoating).

Comment: +1 deceitful. I would have also said **dishonest**.

Answer (score 1):

> What's a word for when someone is wrong, and they know they're wrong, but they insist that they are right?

If they're wrong about an issue involving the knowledge of some subject, but insist they are right, it could be an example of the Dunning-Kruger Effect (involving an overblown estimate of one's own expertise in defiance of data to the contrary) or an instance of cognitive dissonance (involving the inability, or unwillingness, to process new data because it disrupts earlier beliefs).

If it involves something material, such as stolen dog example above, the earlier responses of "liar" and its variants all seem correct.

"In denial" seems to cover both categories listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Like the square root of two, such a person is [*irrational*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irrational).

Comment: I wouldn't use irrational. You can behave in such a way and be very rational (if you are doing it in a malicious way).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming he knows he's wrong (your question isn't clear on this): obstinate, stubborn, unswayable.

If he isn't sure whether he's right or keeps changing his mind: confused, wishy-washy.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question a little.  Yes, the person knows he's in the wrong but is going overboard to try and prove he's right.

Answer (score 0):

10+ year update, just want to add that another (now more commonly heard) answer to this question is "**Gaslighting**".